# get autogenerated id for additional field, using post-persist

Tags: symfony, entity

i have a product with an autogenarete id and also have a productcode field, which grabs values based on user choices combined with the autogenated key to make the productcode. However i cannot grab the autogenate id when inserting a new product.

I used first prepersist & preupdate but that doesn't grab the id when inserting a new product. only when updating it grabs the id

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setProductcode() 
{


  $option1 = $this->option1;   
  $option2 = $this->option2; 
  $id = $this->id;

  $whole = $option1.''.$option2.''.$id;    

  $this->productcode = $whole;


}
```

i try to use postpersist, and changed my field to be nullablae true but it saves the productcode as null.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true, nullable=true)
 */
private $productcode;
```

I used postload and postpersist together and it does show the productcode as output.. but it isn't save it the db.

```
 * @ORM\PostLoad
 * @ORM\PostPersist
```

How can i grab the id in the entity to put it in additional field? Thanks in advance!

---

### edit

I made an easyadminsubcriber and it works when i use the pre_persist return.
However the code below is updated to post_persist. but i have trouble implementing the flush function together with  lifecycleeventargs.

i got the following error back

```
Argument 2 passed to App\EventSubscriber\EasyAdminSubscriber::setProductcode() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, string given, called in
```

below is my post_persist code

```
<?php 
# src/EventSubscriber/EasyAdminSubscriber.php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
class EasyAdminSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{


    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'easy_admin.post_persist' => array('setProductcode'),
        );
    }


    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function setProductcode(GenericEvent $event, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

      $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();


        $entity = $event->getSubject();



        if (!($entity instanceof Product)) {
            return;
        }


        $whole = 'yooo'; 


        $entityManager->flush();

        $entity->setProductcode($whole);

        $event['entity'] = $entity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default, the id is only set, when the entity is *flushed* to the database. this means, you have to generate your product code after you have flushed the entity and then flush again. doctrine can't use some fancy magic to determine the id before it actually hears back from the database, so there's not really another way. (if you want to do all of this in-entity, I can't imagine another practical and clean way to do this)

**update**

you should use PostPersist (while keeping PreUpdate).

> The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event. ([source](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html))

so, the generated primary key is available there. However, this is only *after* you flushed the entity. So, you'd have to flush *again* to write the productcode to the database as well.

create proper event handlers (because "setProductcode" is a setter, not an event handler, at least name-wise)

```
/**
 * PostPersist triggers after the _creation_ of entities in db
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 */
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $this->setProductcode();
    // need to flush, so that changes are written to database
    $args->getObjectManager()->flush();
}   

/**
 * PreUpdate triggers before changes are written to db
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function preUpdate() {
    $this->setProductcode(); 
    // don't need to flush, this happens before the database calls
}
```

(see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument for further information)

(disclaimer: this answer was heavily edited since it first was created, leaving the connected comments partly without relevant references)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
1) -> can you flush in the enity file itself? i am a bit confused as you can call      * @ORM\PostPersist but you cannot flush? i don't know all avaialbel options ..or do i have to write that in the controller?
2) i am not so familiar with transaction.
3) thats indeed a possibility. but i don't know how to
4) yeah i guess i can do that but i thought for future purposes it's maybe handy to have it saved in the db
5) how would you then add a number to the productcode? which is ascending.. 
Thanks so far though! i appreciate the feedback

Comment: oh, you're right about the post-persist. however, you would have to flush again, because the change to your product code is only done after your wrote it to the database. ...

Comment: @Missblues you're right, I was on the wrong train of thought there ... i updated my answer.

Comment: No worries, i try to be clear in my questions, but usually i write too much and then it can become messy. 
Anyway, i understand that i have to flush but i don't know where/how to put that. To give some extra background. i use easyadmin to handle all the the admincontrollers and extending the admincontrollers with a multilangual setup isn't ideal with easyadmin. So that's why i look for solutions to handle everything in the entity file/ or maybe other solutions?

Comment: @Missblues easyadmin bundle ... mh ... you could add an event listener for the post_create event, inject the entitymanger and just call flush there... maybe ... https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#customization-based-on-symfony-events

Comment: i updated my inital code with the eventlistener but i have trouble inject the entitymanger for flush.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192834/discussion-between-jakumi-and-missblues).

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to persist the productcode if it is just a concatenation of other columns? What about just using an efficient getter?

```
public function getProductcode() 
{
  if(!empty($this->productcode)){
    return $this->productcode;
  }

  if(empty($this->id)){
    return "to be determined";
  }

  $this->productcode = $this->option1 . $this->option2 . $this->id;

  return $this->productcode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. yeah i just thought for future references/expansions it might be better if it's actually stored.  is this not common?

Comment: It is already stored in it's components, and that makes it somewhat redundant to repeat the data in a different format, unless you are using it as an index, but you already have the primary key `id` which should be most efficient for looking up results, and indexes can be set on multiple columns, so I cannot see a need for a separate column in this case especially if causes this much headache.

Comment: I see. if i don't do anything else with the id then yeah it's maybe not nesecarly. However i do like to perform some functions on the id to change output etc (also for future addons). and if a postpersist exist to be able to get the id why not use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i have now 2 solutions to set the autogenerate id in another field (by not using the controller). First one is directly in entity file itself as shown in @jakumi answer.

```
   public function setProductcode()
    {

      $part = $this->producttype->gettypenumber();
      $id1 = $this->id;
      $part = sprintf("%03d", $id1);

      $whole = $part1.''.$part2;    

      return $this->productcode= $whole;

    }


/**
 * PostPersist triggers after the _creation_ of entities in db
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 */
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {


    $this->setPoductcode();
    // need to flush, so that changes are written to database
    $args->getObjectManager()->flush();
}   

/**
 * PreUpdate triggers before changes are written to db
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function preUpdate() {


    $this->setProductcode();
    // don't need to flush, this happens before the database calls
}
```

Another solutions is to use the eventsubscriber.

```
<?php 
# src/EventSubscriber/EasyAdminSubscriber.php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
class EasyAdminSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{




    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {

        $this->em = $em;
    }



    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'easy_admin.post_persist' => array('setProductcode'),
        );
    }



    public function setProductcode(GenericEvent $event)
    {


        $entity = $event->getSubject();

        if (!($entity instanceof Product)) {
            return;
        }


        $this->em->flush();

        $entity->setProductcode();

        $this->em->flush();

    }
}
```

and my entity code with postpersist & preupdate

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setProductcode() 
{


    $part1 = $entity->getProducttype()->getTypenumber();
    $id1 = $entity->getId();
    $part2 = sprintf("%03d", $id1);
    $whole = $part1.$part2; 

  $this->productcode = $whole;


}
```

Thanks @Jakumi for explanation & guidelines for both solutions.